# SyntaxError while running Protractor from eclipse

Tags: protractor

I am trying to run my protractor tests from eclipse and its throwing below error:

```
C:\ProtractorWorkspace\TestProtractor\node_modules\protractor\built\logger.js:75
    info(...msgs) {
         ^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ProtractorWorkspace\TestProtractor\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
```

Versions I am using are:

`Node`: `6.10.1`
`Protractor`: `5.1.1`

`NPM`: `3.10.10`

Comment: Paste your confi file here

Comment: @SureshSalloju: Below is the config file:

Comment: @SureshSalloju: Below is the config file:                              exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],
  capabilities : {
        'browserName' : 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions' : {
            'binary' : 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google Chrome (Local)/chrome.exe',
            'args' : [],
            'extensions' : []
   
        }
  }
};